# Emergency calling using cordova android app when mobile in lock mode

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, cordova-2.0.0

i am going to implement emergency calling in cordova phonegap. For safety purpose, app which can provide calling functionality (user can save emergency phone number using app user can edit whenever he/she want).

I cant find way to move forward. please help me out. I even dont know is this possible or not using cordova.

Comment: "Emergency calling" has a *very specific definition*, tied to the emergency numbers for a given country or region (e.g., 911 in the US). Are you looking to place calls to official emergency numbers? If so, on Android, this is only possible if your app is installed in the privileged ('system') partition, or if your app is signed by the same signing key that signed the device firmware.

Comment: calling for safety in emergency situation (emergency number which is provided by user).  Now I want this feature for country India. Is any way?

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Comment: No i am not looking to place calls to officials emergency numbers. i am looking to place calls to phone number which is provided by user in app as a emergency number.  For example, I can use your mobile number as emergency number or my fathers, brothers number as emergency mobile number....

Comment: In traditional Java-based Android development, you would use `startActivity()` with an `ACTION_CALL` `Intent`, supplying the phone number as a `tel:` `Uri` (e.g., `tel:1234567890`). This will require the `CALL_PHONE` permission, which on Android 6.0+ will require runtime permissions. I do not use Cordova much and I do not know if there is an existing plugin that wraps up `ACTION_CALL` functionality.